# Why I can't append HTML in <body> from content script for SOME websites from my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that appends HTML inside the body tag. It's working fine for Google.com, but does not work on some websites, such as Amazon.com and Stackoverflow.com.

I need it to work on Amazon.com.

**manifest.json**:

```
{

    "manifest_version" : 2,

    "permissions": [ "activeTab", "tabs", "background", "*://www.amazon.com/*", "storage", "unlimitedStorage" ],

   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "js/background.js" ]      
   },

  "content_scripts" : [
    {    
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": ["lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js", "lib/jquery-ui.min.js", "js/main.js" ],
      "css" : ["main.css"]      
    }
  ],

}
```

**contentScript.js**

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('view.html'), function(data) {        
    alert("appending to body: " + data);
    $(data).appendTo('body');          
});
```

Alert works fine and I see the html from view.html, but $(data).appendTo('body'); does not work. It does not show up in DOM after execution of this line and no error messages or warning in console.

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I changed the code to $("body").prepend(data); everything started working fine.

Problem solved or should I say there was no problem in the first place.